# call function without return value in Sass

Tags: sass

I want to be able to check two colors for their contrast and emit a warning if the contrast is below a certain threshold. Here is my code:

```
@function contrast-check($color1, $color2, $threshold: 4.5) {
  @if contrast($color1, $color2) < $threshold {
    @warn 'contrast #{$contrast} between #{$color1} and #{$color2} too low!';
  }
}
```

The trouble is that I can not call this function from anywhere. Here is what I tried:

- `contrast-check(#fff, #000);` - Error: Invalid CSS after '...': expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "rast-check(#fff..."
- `$: contrast-check(#fff, #000);` - Error: Function contrast-check did not return a value
- `* {test: contrast-check(#fff, #000);}` - Error: Function contrast-check did not return a value

I could convert the function to a mixing. Then it would be possible to call it as intended. But mixins can not be used from other function.

Another option could be to return an arbitrary value. This would work, but would also be extremly hacky because you would have to assign that value to a throw-away variable each time you call the function.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: Returning `null` as an arbitrary value might be a nice option because any properties with value `null` will be skipped in the output.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you have to do.  You're just asking for opinions at this point (and asking for opinions is off-topic).

Comment: Cimmanon. I'm quite sure he is able to understand the error message but doesn't want to use a return value because there's nothing to return. He is asking if there's a better way of doing this and this is a common problem which has been debated on the SASS Github issues page so it's a very valid and helpful question. Stop trolling the SASS tag. If you haven't got anything useful to contribute....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do, there is a discussion about it on the project's Git issues page here.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1348

You can return null from function but it seems as though the creators of SASS just don't want you doing this kind of thing so best bet is to just use a mixin, even though you're not mixing anything in. I know it's semantically wrong but...

This was the issue that made me reaslise that SASS just wasn't up to the job of doing what I needed to do and I'm now writing a postcss plugin to do the job instead. Don't know if that route would have an mileage for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I think the argument that functions without a return value are not the common case is valid.